# What is the shortest Python code to get a maximum from the two discrete functions?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

For given two discrete functions like this:

```
y1 = lambda(x): x**2
y2 = lambda(x): (x-1.5)*10
x1 = np.linspace(0,12,50)
x2 = np.linspace(1,10,12)
plot(x1, y1(x1), '.-')
plot(x2, y2(x2), '.-')
```

[image]

what is the shortest Python code to get the maximum of them?

Comment: What is the one that you've tried?

Comment: you mean the max for every point?

Comment: Yes, in each point. Note, the functions defined at different points.

Comment: @DirtyBit that will not work, because you have to use `max` on an iterable. You are using it on a function.

Comment: Oh, yes iterate over it for each point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
x = np.sort(np.r_[x1, x2])
y = np.maximum(np.interp(x, x1, y1(x1)), np.interp(x, x2, y2(x2)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Amazing python!

Answer (score 1):

Well you just need to use the built-in `max` function on the y values.

```
f1max = max([y1(x) for x in x1])
f2max = max([y2(x) for x in x2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# -------------------
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TKAgg');
from pylab import plot,show

# ---------------------
y1 = lambda(x): x**2
y2 = lambda(x): (x-1.5)*10
x1 = np.linspace(0,12,50)
x2 = np.linspace(1,10,12)
# --------------------
ymax=np.max((y1(x1),y2(x1)),axis=0)
plot(x1, y1(x1), '.-')
plot(x2, y2(x2), '.-')
plot(x1, ymax, 'k',lw=2.0)
show()
```